sampling low-voltage HVAC signals with digital hardware
I'd like to monitor my heat pump HVAC system digitally, probably with an Arduino. The goal is to produce simple graphs of all the thermostat signals, so I can monitor how long it's running, first- versus second-stage, call for backup heat, etc.  So I need a way to convert the various thermostat 24vac signals (G, Y, O/B, W, etc) to a small DC voltage (3.3 or 5).
I could use a diode rectifier, a smoothing capacitor, and a resistor voltage divider (or a cheap off-the-shelf product that combines these) - referencing the DC voltage to the C-wire.
But I'm not sure if this will work right, because I can't seem to find any information about the electrical characteristics of the low-voltage signals.
There's a line voltage to 24vac transformer, usually in the air handler, that provides a constant 24vac between the R and C wires.   The thermostat "asserts" this onto the other wires (partially listed in 1st paragraph) in order to activate various modes of the system (e.g. 'Y' to turn on the compressor).
But what does it do when it's not asserting 24vac onto one of those wires ? Does it put the C-wire potential on them ?   Or does it tri-state them ?   I think there must be some tri-stating going on, because typically there are THREE 'W' terminals tied together (on thermostat, airhandler, and compressor).  Normally the thermostat asserts 'W' to call for backup heat.  But it's also possible for the compressor to assert 'W', indicating that it's going into defrost mode.  So there would be a potential conflict on the 'W' wire if the thermostat was not tri-stating its 'W' signal (or if the compressor was not tri-stating its 'W' pin when the thermostat is asserting 'W').
If tri-stating were going on, my digital signal might not go to a logical '0' when the corresponding thermostat signal is de-asserted.  I suppose it might go to zero quickly enough (I don't need to sample more than once per minute at the most) by the smoothing capacitor draining thru the resistor divider (that reduces the recitified 24 vac to 3.3vdc).
Thoughts ? Will this work ?  Is there a simpler way ?   Are there products one can tie to the thermostat wires to do this monitoring for you ?    I know the Google Nest thermostats handle all this for you, via the computer interface.  But the "professional" Homneywell one that I've installed seems not to have this capability.

Do you literally need to monitor every thermostat wire? Or do you just need to know when the system is "on"? Or do you need to know separately "heat on" vs. "a/c on" vs. "fan on"?

Yes, want to monitor them all.   So can know if it's running high- or low-stage, is it calling for backup heat, etc.

I want to be able to produce simple graphs.

Edited for clarification: I want graphs of all the thermostat signals.

What kind of system, and are you willing to void your warranty? Mitsubishi's web interface for their mini splits actually communicates with the control board via TTL level rs232. If you search the usual hacker pages you can find at least one person who has interfaced this to an Arduino or raspberry pi. That would give you the temperature as measured at the mini split head, which, of course, is not necessarily the temperature for the rest of the room. (I don't want to void my warranty yet, so I am settling for external temperature sensing and sending dynamic IR controls.)

Another option is to find a smart thermostat that can report the information. Not as much fun as building hardware and writing code. But probably a lot cheaper if you can find COTS to do it.

This Honeywell thermostat is one of there fanciest, and has wifi connectivity.   But unless I'm missing something, it cannot report the info.   And yeah, fun.

That sounds TOO complicated (trying to interface directly into the control board).

You didn't come out and say this part, but having the data you're wanting to collect will be helpful in understanding HVAC operating patterns, correlation to outdoor weather, and especially in estimating and later quantifying the benefit of any future energy-efficiency home improvement projects.
You've got a very good handle on how the thermostat, its R and C connections, and the W/Y/G control wires all work.
In the olden days relays were used in the furnace. The 24 vac transformer was as you described, with one terminal connected out to the red "R" wire up to the heating-only thermostat. A white "W" wire came back from the thermostat and connected to one side of a relay's coil. The other side of the relay coil was wired to the transformer -- today we call that "C", but in these old furnaces, this node didn't get labeled. (Do a search on this site for "where's my C terminal??" or similar; you'll find lots of photos of these appliances. Some of them have discrete transformers and relays with pigtails wire-nutted together, not even a PCB!) The relay coil was effectively a medium-strong pull-down on the W, and later Y and G, control inputs.
A thermostat will open-circuit or tri-state its W/Y/G outputs when these are de-asserted. And, in fact, one can install multiple thermostats in parallel so that any one of them can call for heat, cool, or fan. (A "wired-or" configuration.)
A furnace or air handler control board faces the same need as you've identified for your monitoring solution: to accurately recognize when a call for heat/cool/fan has terminated. Though these control boards no longer have relay coils behind the input pins, you can expect they'll still present some kind of pull-down on each wire. The control wire won't be left floating with no bias at all.
I think you can devise a circuit that will probably include a diode for rectification, maybe resistors forming a voltage divider, an RC filter network to smooth the half-wave rectification and remove high-frequency noise, maybe a current-limiting series resistor, and an opto-isolator which will convert the 24 vac signal to digital logic at a level suitable for your MCU. If you've never played with pspice/ltspice/etc before to model a circuit like this, now's your chance!

Yeah, I like LTSpice.    Why an opto-isolator ?   The input impedance  of the conversion circuit should be very high, and the thermostat pins are rated for 500ma or more.

Maybe your circuit will be embedded inside the air handler and derive its power from the 24 vac transformer; in that case optos serve little purpose. But I suggested them for voltage isolation in case the digital circuit would be floated away from the common of the 24 vac transformer, which is likely tied to earth ground. You might tie your digital circuit's ground to earth ground anyway, but if your circuit would be remote from the air handler and might connect to other equipment (a PC via a USB/serial cable?) then some isolation could be good.

I'm imagining just a short piece of thermostat cable coming out of the air handler, and the device just sits on top of it - which is just the Ardiuno, and 6 or so copies of this AC->DC circuit.  Interface to the thing via wifi.

Found this opto-coupler, that takes AC input: https://www.vishay.com/docs/83675/sfh620a.pdf. Might be just the ticket.

Greg, you say "A thermostat will open-circuit or tri-state its W/Y/G outputs when these are de-asserted. And, in fact, one can install multiple thermostats in parallel".  This clears up my confusion about how the W wire works; in a heat pump, it's generally connected to three terminals - on the thermostat, the compressor, and the air handler.  So either the thermostat (if backup heating is required), or the compressor (if it goes into defrost mode),, can assert W and activate the backup heat.

Here's the circuit I ended up using:

One copy for each thermostat signal - with one input connected to the thermostat signal (e.g. G, Y1, Y2, W, O) and the other connected to the thermostat common signal 'C'.   The outputs go into an Arduino.
The 10K resistor provides for pretty minimal loading of the thermostat signals (about 2ma from each), and I believe the diodes in the opto-coupler (SFH628A-3) previous a spurious logic-1 when the thermostat signal is tri-stated. The LED just provides visual indication of each signal's being asserted.
